# Why does detectChanges method cause "Attempt to use a destroyed view" Error?

Tags: angular

`Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges at viewDestroyedError`

I get this error when going to another page while trying to trigger change detection by using `detectChanges` method in a component. I discovered that I don't get the error if I used `markForCheck` method. I'm aware of the difference from the two methods but I just don't get why `detectChanges` would cause this error during the destroy process. Any ideas?

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    data: any;
    constructor(
      private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
      private somethingService: SomethingService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.somethingService.getData().subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that allows to reproduce - ideally a minimal working reproduction on http://stackblitz.com

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Added a bit of code

Comment: you're triggering `detectChanges` after the component has been destroyed. add `ngOnDestroy` and you will see it triggered

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I figured it out but why would the change detector get triggered after the component has been destroyed?

Comment: @DongBinKim, because you're triggering it with `detectChanges`

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to call `detectChanges`

If you still want to use it you can also just ensure the observable is unsubscribed on destroy.

```
serviceSubscription:any
ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceSubscription = this.somethingService.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.serviceSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Another way is to use the async pipe

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.somethingService.getData();
}
```

with

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">
```

(or similar)

The `async` pipe will subscribe/unsubscribe automatically

Comment: I'm using `detectChanges` in order to run the change detection of this component because this component is taking `OnPush` at the moment. And I found out the error keeps coming out regardless of the implementation of `unsubscribe`. If I try `if (!this.changeDetector['destroyed']) {` condition, the error doesn't show up anymore but I have no clue what's wrong with `detactChanges`

Comment: Weird. I'd expect unsubscribing to fix it. Can you use the `|async` pipe like shown? (fixed a few things in my code)

Comment: I need to handle a few things with the subscribed data in real code so I'm afraid I can't apply async pipe :( Appreciate your help though.

Comment: I assume you're aware that you can use `.map(...)` to modify arriving data (instead of `subscribe()`).

Comment: Can you reproduce in a http://stackblitz.com? This would make it easier to investigate and try things.